# A simple Makefile that doesn't create the executable file

Tags: makefile

I have the following Makefile:

```
CC = gcc
OBJS = a.o b.o c.o
EXEC = prog
DEBUG = #-g for debug
CFLAGS = -std=c99 -Wall -Werror $(DEBUG)

$(EXEC) : $(OBJS)
a.o : a.c a.h b.h
b.o : b.c b.h
c.o : c.c c.h b.h

clean:
        rm -f $(OBJS) $(EXEC)
```

It creates the object files but it doesn't create the executable file - `prog`.
How do I fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(EXEC): $(OBJS)
        $(CC) -o $@ $(CFLAGS) $(OBJS)
```

Basically, when you list multiple objects as dependencies, the implicit rules can't be used, so you have to write the command to execute yourself.  The `$@` is a shorthand for `$(EXEC)` in this case; it is the target being created.